Bootstrap 5 row/col structure
i want to achieve grid structure as illustrated in the attached image. My code is not providing the required results. Any help in this regard shall be highly appreciated.


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container ">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class=" col-12 col-md-8 bg-primary ">
      1
    </div>
    <div class=" col-12 col-md-4 ">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-12 bg-info">
          2
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 bg-warning">
          3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>





Have you tried anything else? Have you read the docs? Have you searched for similiar questions? This is not the way to ask here. Please read [ask] and provide the necessary details.

Try it.
Is it consistent with what you want?
Among the breakpoints provided by bootstrap, the md size is 768px.
The 786px you want seems to need customization.


/* Medium   md  ≥768px */
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8 bg-primary">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 col-md-12 bg-info">
          2
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-12 bg-warning">
          3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



